# Is there a way to combine 2 characters before a space?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function RandChars(n As Long, Optional alphabet As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789") As String
  Dim chars() As String
  Dim i As Long, k As Long
  k = Len(alphabet)
  ReDim chars(1 To n)
  With Application.WorksheetFunction
    For i = 1 To n
        chars(i) = Mid(alphabet, .RandBetween(1, k), 1)
        
    Next i
  End With

  RandChars = Join(chars, " ")
End Function
```

This code shows is for example: " 6 z l t v c p z a s 8 f ...."

Is there any way to tweak the code such that it'll display: "6z lt vc pz as 8f"?

Comment: Yes, there is a way, change the code `Join(chars, " ")` because this adds a " " between the characters, and you do not want that, because you only want that every other character to happen. A simple For/Next loop could do that.

Answer (score 3):

You could just double up your line:

```
chars(i) = Mid(alphabet, .RandBetween(1, k), 1)
```

to

```
chars(i) = Mid(alphabet, .RandBetween(1, k), 1) & Mid(alphabet, .RandBetween(1, k), 1)
```

As per the comment I made I thought I might try something to avoid duplicating the letter/number for the second value. For example to avoid getting "gg 55 rr" etc. So here's what I got for that as well:

```
Function RandChars(n As Long, Optional alphabet As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789") As String
Dim chars() As String
Dim chars2 As String
Dim i As Long, k As Long
k = Len(alphabet)
ReDim chars(1 To n)
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    For i = 1 To n
        chars(i) = Mid(alphabet, .RandBetween(1, k), 1)
FindChars2:
        chars2 = Mid(alphabet, .RandBetween(1, k), 1)
        If chars(i) = chars2 Then
            GoTo FindChars2
        Else
            chars(i) = chars(i) & chars2
        End If
    Next i
End With

RandChars = Join(chars, " ")

End Function
```

Comment: Just know in case you don't want it, there is the chance they you could get 2 of the same letter/number together. To avoid it would be adding more code to check against what the first randbetween got and then making the second one not get that same value.

Answer (score 2):

I used Regular Expressions and also added an optional argument to the function call to enable you to decide the "size' of the group.

eg:

```
Function RandChars(n As Long, Optional group As Long = 2, Optional alphabet As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789") As String
  Dim chars() As String
  Dim i As Long, k As Long
  k = Len(alphabet)
  ReDim chars(1 To n)
  With Application.WorksheetFunction
    For i = 1 To n
        chars(i) = Mid(alphabet, .RandBetween(1, k), 1)
    Next i
  End With

Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "(.{" & group & "})(?=.)"
    .Global = True
    RandChars = .Replace(Join(chars, ""), "$1 ")
End With

End Function
```

eg:

```
randchars(12) --> xk pj hr k5 i8 7d 
randchars(12,3) --> qg3 54s sec myu
```

***Explanation of the Regex***

### Group Characters

*(Explanation is for two characters but works for any n)*

```
(.{2})(?=.)
```

- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) `(.{2})`

  - [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.{2}`

    - [Exactly 2 times](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{2}`
- [Assert that the regex below can be matched starting at this position (positive lookahead)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=.)`

  - [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.`

**Replacement string**

$1·

- [Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$1`
- [Insert the character “ ” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)

Created with [RegexBuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Just in addition to and based on @Simon's code a shorter version:

```
Function RandChars(n As Long, Optional alphabet As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789") As String
  Dim k As Long: k = Len(alphabet)
  Dim chars() As String: ReDim chars(1 To n)
  With Application.WorksheetFunction
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To n
        chars(i) = Mid(alphabet, .RandBetween(1, k), 1) & String((i - 1) Mod 2, " ")
    Next i
  End With
  'return function result
  RandChars = Trim(Join(chars, ""))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

A straight-forward creation of the string you want may prove to be the simplest solution.

```
Function RandChars(n As Long, _
                   Optional Alphabet As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789") _
                   As String
    
    Dim Fun     As String
    Dim Chars() As String
    Dim i       As Long
    Dim k       As Long
    
    k = Len(Alphabet)
    ReDim Chars(1 To n)
    For i = 1 To n
        Fun = Fun & Mid(Alphabet, WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, k), 1)
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then Fun = Fun & " "
    Next i
    
    RandChars = Trim(Fun)
End Function
```

Comment: You may want to remove the terminal space that will result if you have an even number of characters.